# Does America's Birthright Citizenship law apply to the American side of the International Space Station?

Tags: iss, nasa, astronauts, law

In a scenario in which a pregnant Russian woman were to give birth while visiting the International Space Station, and if she were to give birth while on the American side of the ISS, would that baby be an American citizen based on America's Birthright Citizenship law?

In other words, does America's Birthright Citizenship law apply to the American side/sections of the ISS?

Comment: space law is absolutely *on-topic.*

Comment: Note that it's generally assumed that a zero-gee + cosmic ray environment will very likely lead to pregnancy complications, so the scenario is unlikely to actually occur.

Comment: Does a child born in a US ship get US citizenship?  Space law is not that different from sea law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Seems Like It**

Absurd hypotheticals aside, the [Intergovernmental Agreement](https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/107683.pdf) (IGA) specifies in Article V:

> [E]ach Partner shall retain jurisdiction and control over the elements it registers...and over personnel in or on the Space Station who are its nationals.

[This](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/International_Space_Station/International_Space_Station_legal_framework) ESA resource summarizes:

> The Intergovernmental Agreement allows the Space Station Partners States to extend their national jurisdiction in outer space, so the elements they provide (e.g. laboratories) are assimilated to the territories of the Partners States.

For ESA astronauts/modules, I believe this means property/jurisdiction of the EU.

[This](https://www.inverse.com/article/44634-space-lawyer-iss-multinational-monster) article interviewing a "space lawyer" explains it essentially as:

> multiple embassies floating right over our heads

I think it's fair to say that if a Russian woman gave birth in, say, the Destiny module it would probably be treated the same as if she had walked into the U.S. and given birth.  Of course, the U.S. and Russia could just as easily say that they are making an exception to the IGA for an unorthodox situation and that would probably be the end of discussion.

Comment: "Jurisdiction of the EU" Given the differences in laws and jurisdictions between member states, how would that work there? Which law would be applied?

Comment: The second link adds: "The European States are being treated as one homogenous entity, called the European Partner on the Space Station. But any of the European States may extend their respective national laws and regulations to the European elements, equipment and personnel."  This is almost more confusing.  I'm not very familiar with what jurisdiction the EU has vs. member states, and I'm not sure if the EU and the aforementioned "European Partner" consist of the same member states, so I won't venture a guess here.

Comment: Well, this clearly deserves [its own question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/how-does-european-jurisdiction-in-the-iss-works) then

Comment: Nope, jurisdiction and control is not the same as being on national territory.  Added an answer below.

Comment: FYI the "European partners" mentioned in the IGA are the (14 I think?) ESA member states that actually signed the IGA themselves and actively participate in ISS operations. Not all ESA Members do.

Comment: Most EU countries do not give citizenship by birth location (they consider the citizenship of the parents. Typically: if both parents are citizen of country X, child will be too, independently where did he born. If the citizenship of the parents differ, there might be problems but not too much (more paperwork)). There is no citizenship only because you born there (but typically, much easier).

Comment: However, practice is that no pregnant woman is sent to space. If it would happen, the likely political outcome would be that the country of the mother would very happily give the citizenship to the baby on the spot, on a politician-accelerated quick channel. And many fanfare, celebration, etc, "First human born in space belongs to us, wow". The mother had no intention to get any other citizenship to the baby because it would look like treason, and she would be loyal to her country (which sent she to the space).

Comment: Being in weightlessness would be at least life-threatening, possibly deadly for the baby. Babies vomit a lot, he/she would likely drown. He/she would be also deadly danger also for the astronauts there (imagine if he poops...). Very likely he/she, with the mother, would come back on the spot with some emergency craft. It is not sure that he/she would survive the 3g of the reentry (the 1g of the out-of-womb life is already hard for a baby).

Answer (score 6):

No. Although as stated in another answer, the International side of the ISS is under the jurisdiction and control of the relevant partners, that doesn't mean that those modules are the TERRITORY of the relevant states. It is a lot like embassies, which, despite the Simpsons episode to the contrary, are absolutely not territory of their home state, despite being subject to their home state laws. The 14th Amendment of the U.S. constitution requires being born "in the United States" AND being subject to the jurisdiction of the United States (eg not a foreign diplomat located in the U.S.) for birthright citizenship. Babies on an American module of the ISS would meet the second criteria but not the first.

Adding a reference to an excellent SE answer about why [babies born in U.S. embassies](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030101.html) are NOT automatically American citizens. Same reasons I've described above. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/are-persons-born-in-u-s-embassies-u-s-citizens-if-their-parents-are-not-citiz